# Exprimer « measured to be »

Tags: traduction, anglais, science

> We have also measured the velocity field in the pipe to be:
>
> Nous avons également mesuré le champ de vitesse dans le tuyau (to be):

(suivi d'un système de trois équations)

Google translate donne « à»  pour « to be », mais je me demande si c'est correct et, en plus, s'il y a d'autres façons pour exprimer « to be » dans ce contexte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the phrases  "measured to be", "defined to be", "understood to be", "thought to be",… is used, they are followed by a complement which is the result of respectively measuring, defining, understanding, thinking,…

They can be translated in various ways; in the case of your example the following are possibilities when what follows is a measure.

1. La mesure du champ de vitesse dans le tuyau, que nous avons également faite, est de (*ou* est égale à)…
2. Nous avons également mesuré le champ de vitesse dans le tuyau et il est de (*ou* est égal à)…
3. La mesure du champ de vitesse dans le tuyau, nous l'avons également établie, est de (*ou* est égale à)…
4. Nous avons également établi la mesure du champ de vitesse dans le tuyau comme étant…

**If what follows is an equation or a set of equations little modification is needed.**

1. La mesure du champ de vitesse dans le tuyau, que nous avons également faite, est:
2. Nous avons également établi la mesure du champ de vitesse dans le tuyau comme étant:
3. La mesure du champ de vitesse dans le tuyau, nous l'avons également déterminée, est égale à
4. Nous avons également établi la mesure du champ de vitesse dans le tuyau comme étant

Comment: Ne pas oublier dans la liste des possibles, la moindre des choses pour une *valeur* qui est de **valoir** ;-)

Comment: « Établir une mesure » et « établir une mesure comme étant » me semblent très douteux en plus d'être particulièrement pompeux. « La valeur de quelque chose est égale à » me conviendrait, « la mesure de quelque chose est égale à » non.

Comment: @Stéphane Assez bizarre…La mesure agraire du champ est A; A est égal à 100 m²; donc la mesure agraire du champ est égale à 100 m² *ou* est de 100 m² (semble peu important). Cela me parait tout à fait naturel, pas le moins du monde pompeux; il faudra que je garde votre commentaire à l'esprit quand même; y aurait-il une majorité à trouver cette forme impropre?.

Answer (score 1):

On peut formuler ça de cette façon :

> Nous avons mesuré le champ de vitesse suivant dans le tuyau :
>   […]

J'éviterais cependant d'utiliser « également » dans ce cas. Si un enchainement est vraiment nécessaire « de plus » est probablement plus approprié.

Comment: Je n'aime pas beaucoup la place de *suivant*. Je le préfèrerais à la fin. De plus, *sauf si* il s'agit d'un CR de TP scolaire alors je préfèrerais une tournure plus impersonnelle : *Le champ... a été mesuré*.  Partant sous cette forme, le *to be* trouve tout naturellement son équivalent en ***valant*** : *Le champ... a été mesuré valant xyz.*

Comment: Je le préfèrerais aussi à la fin, mais ce n'est pas interdit de formuler ça ainsi. Pour ce qui est de la tournure impersonelle, c'est un autre sujet.

Comment: Alors va pour : *Dans le tuyau, nous avons mesuré le champ de vitesse suivant :*

Comment: En vue de rendre « champ de vitesse » et « tuyau » indissociables, comme cela semble être le but, « Nous trouvons que le champ de vitesse dans le tuyau a la mesure suivante : » donne une solution.